# What does "for" mean in this context?

Tags: sentence-meaning

> Here's a description of each column in the dataset:
>
> Year -- **The year the data** in the row is **for**

What does "for" mean? Acually,"the year the date" hard to understand too.
I guess it means "the data in the row shows as the Year is stand for the year.
Any explanation is helpful,thinks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "for" is a preposition and, in this sense, it means "belonging to". As a non sequitur, I know a lot of people treat "data" as a singular noun, but I still hearken to "data" as the plural of the singular noun "datum", but I know I'm in the minority here.  Suffice it to say, I would translate it this way:

> "The year the data in the row are for" = "The data in the row are for this year" = "The data in the row belong to this year"

Comment: wonderful answer,is it uses to emphasize the noun by putting preposition  at  the end of the sentence?

Comment: Well, it's a subordinate clause, but lots of prepositions go at the end, especially in questions: "Who(m) are you talking **to**?" "How long are you here **for**?" In subordinate clauses, here are some examples: "I don't know **what this is for**." "what this is for" = "this is for what"; "This is the the painting that I was talking **about**." "that I was talking about" = "I was talking about that (painting)."